# lxml.etree import error w python2/3 in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: python, 22.04, lxml

I have this strange import error with lxml.etree

```
 [exec] Creating deb files
 [exec] Traceback (most recent call last):
 [exec]   File "../../../../filtec-bin/packages/alpacaKV_packaging/packager.py", line 20, in <module>
 [exec]     import lxml.etree as ET
 [exec] ImportError: No module named lxml.etree
```

this build script has worked for us for many years in our previous build but does not here. I've already installed lxml with "pip install lxml"

```
$:~/eclipse-workspace/filtec-src/src$ python --version
Python 2.7.18
$:~/eclipse-workspace/filtec-src/src$ pip install lxml
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: lxml in /home/james/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (4.9.1)
```

Comment: For me upgrading to 22.04 broke many python2 packages, reinstalling all the pip packages that were currently installed at the time of the update fixed it for me: pip list | awk -F ' ' '{print $1}' | xargs -L1 -I{} pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall {}

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, and I fixed it this way on Ubuntu 20.04 with Python 3.1.8.

Go to the terminal and type these commands:

1. `cd /home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/lxml` (Change the "user" keyword according to your system.)
2. `mv etree.pyx etree.py`

You can do it manually by going to:

```
/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/lxml
```

and rename `etree.pyx` to `etree.py`.
Then try to `import lxml.etree`, and hopefully it will work for you.